# T-SQL loop through two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2016

I have been unable to find a working solution for below dilemma.

I am using SQL Server 2016 and have the 2 tables shown below in a database.

`Users` table:

```
Id   Name
----------
1    Lisa
2    Paul
3    John
4    Mike
5    Tom
```

`Role` table:

```
Id   UserId   Role
------------------------
1    3        Manager
2    2,4,5    Developer
3    1        Designer
```

I am looking for T-SQL code that loops through the `Role` table, extracts `UserId`s and retrieves associated name for each `Id` from the `Users` table.

So the looped result would look like this:

```
John
Paul,Mike,Tom
Lisa
```

Comment: Fix your data model.  Don't store numeric ids as delimited strings.  It is simply the wrong way to store data in a relational database.

Comment: And it will only cause you lots of trouble. (Just like here...)

Comment: I agree, but unfortunately I didn't create the Database, I am only stuck with the problem

Comment: Plus, change your mind set. You don't want to loop through your data; that will almost always perform poorly.

Comment: Do you not have the option of changing the database? Just because a database was initially designed poorly doesn't mean you should stick with it; fix the design, fix the problem. Also, what have you tried? A simple search would have likely given you 100's of locked duplicates on SO.

Comment: Someone needs to add a lookup table (or bridge table) with UserId, RoleId,  Role and Name with each combination in single rows !

Comment: _"I have been unable to find a working solution for below dilemma."_ That implies you tried anything. Post what that was. SO expects some evidence of prior effort. Posting what you already tried and didn't work will also help to avoid readers wasting their time by suggesting things that were found not to be suitable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**FOR SQL SERVER 2017**

```
SELECT R1.Id,STRING_AGG(U.Name , ','),R1.Role
FROM Users U
INNER JOIN
(
SELECT R.Id,S.value AS UserId,R.Role
FROM Role R
     CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT (UserID, ',') S
) R1
ON U.Id=R1.UserId
GROUP BY R1.ID,R1.Role
ORDER BY R1.ID;
```

**OR**

**FOR SQL SERVER 2016**

```
WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT R2.ID,U.Name,R2.UserId,R2.Role
FROM Users U
INNER JOIN
(
SELECT R.Id,S.value AS UserId,R.Role
FROM Role R
     CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT (UserID, ',') S
)R2
ON U.id=R2.UserId
)
SELECT DISTINCT R1.Id,
       STUFF((
          SELECT ',' + name
          FROM CTE R3
          WHERE R1.Role = R3.Role
          FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '') AS NAME
          ,R1.Role
FROM CTE AS R1;
```

**OR**

**For Old versions**

```
With CTE AS
(
SELECT r.id,
       u.name, 
       r.Role
FROM Users u 
INNER JOIN Role r
ON ',' + CAST(r.Userid AS NVARCHAR(20)) + ',' like '%,' + CAST(u.id AS NVARCHAR(20)) + ',%'
)
SELECT DISTINCT id,
          STUFF((
          SELECT ',' + name
          FROM CTE md
          WHERE T.Role = md.Role
          FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '') AS NAME,
          Role
FROM
CTE AS T
ORDER BY id
```

**Output**

```
id  NAME            Role
1   John            Manager
2   Paul,Mike,Tom   Developer
3   Lisa            Designer
```

**Demo**

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/04a2d/69

Comment: The OP is using SQL Server 2016. Why not `STRING_SPLIT`?

Comment: Welcome :-) @Cindro

Answer (score 3):

There are several problems going on here. The first issue is that you're storing your values in a delimited format. Next, because you're storing your values in a delimited format, the values are being stored as a `varchar`. This has problems as well, as, as I would *guess* that the value of your column `Id` in the table `Users` is an `int`; meaning an implicit cast is needed and ruining any SARGability.

So, the solution is to fix the problem, in my view. Because you have a many to many relationship, you'll need an extra table. Let's design the tables as you have them right now, anyway:

```
CREATE TABLE Users (Id int, Name varchar(100));
CREATE TABLE Role (Id int, UserId varchar(100), [Role] varchar(100));

INSERT INTO Users
VALUES (1,'Lisa'),
       (2,'Paul'),
       (3,'John'),
       (4,'Mike'),
       (5,'Tom');

INSERT INTO Roles
VALUES(1,'3','Manager'),
      (2,'2,4,5','Developer'),
      (3,'1','Designer');
```

Now, instead we need a new table:

```
CREATE TABLE UserRoles (Id int, UserID int, RoleID int);
```

Now, we can insert the proper rows into the database. As you're using SQL Server 2016, we can use `STRING_SPLIT`:

```
INSERT INTO UserRoles (UserID, RoleID)
SELECT SS.value, R.Id
FROM Roles R
     CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT (UserID, ',') SS;
```

After this, if you want, you could drop your existing column using the following, however, I see no harm in leaving it at the moment:

```
ALTER TABLE Roles DROP COLUMN UserID;
```

Now, we can query the data correctly:

```
SELECT *
FROM Users U
     JOIN UserRoles UR ON U.ID = UR.UserID
     JOIN Roles R ON UR.RoleID = R.Id;
```

If you want to then delimit this data, you can use `STUFF`, but **don't** store it back; I've explained how to correct your data for a reason! :)

```
SELECT [Role],
       STUFF((SELECT ',' + [Name]
              FROM Users U
                   JOIN UserRoles UR ON U.Id = UR.UserID
              WHERE UR.RoleID = R.Id
              FOR XML PATH ('')),1,1,'') AS Users
FROM Roles R;
```

If you were using SQL Server 2017, you'd be able to use [`STRING_AGG`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

*Clean up script:*

```
DROP TABLE UserRoles;
DROP TABLE Users;
DROP TABLE Roles;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this solution:

```
declare @users table (Id int, Name varchar(100))
declare @role table (Id int, UserId varchar(100), [Role] varchar(100))

insert into @users values
(1, 'Lisa'),
(2, 'Paul'),
(3, 'John'),
(4, 'Mike'),
(5, 'Tom')
insert into @role values
(1, '3', 'Manager'),
(2, '2,4,5', 'Developer'),
(3, '1', 'Designer')

select * from @role [r]
join @users [u] on
CHARINDEX(',' + cast([u].Id as varchar(3)) + ',', ',' + [r].UserId + ',', 1) > 0
```

I joined both tables based on occurence `Id` in `UserId`. To make it possible and avoid matches like: `2` is matched to `12`, I decided to match only IDs surrounded by commas. That's why I wrapped in commas `Id` in a query and also wrapped `UserId` in commas, to match IDs at the end and the beginning of `userId`.

This query should give you satisfying result, but to match your desired output exatcly, you have to wrap this query in a CTE and perform `group by` with string concatenation:

```
;with cte as (
    select [r].Id, [r].Role, [u].Name from @role [r]
    join @users [u] on
    CHARINDEX(',' + cast([u].Id as varchar(3)) + ',', ',' + [r].UserId + ',', 1) > 0
)

select Id,
       (select Name + ',' from cte where Id = [c].Id for xml path('')) [Name],
       --I believe this should work in your case, if so, just pick one column from these two
       string_agg(Name + ',') [Name2],
       Role
from cte [c]
group by Id, Role
```